# Error R Sweave and Knitr Plugins at WinEdt 8.0?

Tags: errors, compiling, sweave, winedt, knitr

I try a simple example document .rnw at WinEdt with R Sweave Plugin like this :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\textbf{hello world}
<<echo=TRUE,fig=TRUE>>=
x<-1:40
y<-rnorm(40)
plot(x,y)

@



\end{document}
```

So, i am running  my document with R Sweave plugin but i get error like this

[image: tes r sweave and knitr at Winedt]

```
Error Launching Console Application 
Command Line:   "\bin\x64\Rscript" "C:\Users\hirwanto\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 8\Contrib\R-Sweave\Sweave.R" "Ass.Rnw"
Startup Folder: D:

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't know **How to resolve it**  ? Before I can running my document.rnw and .rmd.

Answer (score 2):

[To get this off the unanswered list]

First of all be sure to have R installed.

Then please uninstall the R-Sweave plugin (obsolete) and install the new [RManager plugin](http://www.winedt.org/config/modes/RManager.html).

This new one is able to detect the path to Rscript.exe from the Windows registry, so you will not have problems like this anymore!